# How to combine Material-table with Material-UI Dialog? (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, web, material-ui, material-table

I am using action(https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions) in my rows, but I want the action to be clicked and open a dialog(https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/).

How to write this in actions? It seems that Material-UI just append the  next to the click. Is it possible to do that in Material-Table?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out [material-table-formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-table-formik)

Comment: There could be other developers searching for a similar solution. It would be helpful if you could share a working example or a sandbox @Domino987. There is significantly less documentation on the npm package. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why you are using Material-Table package?
you can use the Material-UI Table component.
You can see here: [enter link description here](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#table)

and you can see an example that i did here:
[enter link description here](https://jzbml.csb.app/)

when you click on the pencil it will open the dialog